# I cannot draw bounding box correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, torch

I can't draw the bounding box correctly.

```
img = Image.open("/content/drive/MyDrive/58125_000893_Sideline_frame298.jpg").convert('RGB')
convert_tensor = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()

img=convert_tensor(img)
width=15
top=456
height=16
left=1099
img=img*255
boxs=[left,top,top+width,left+height]
print(boxs)
boxs=torch.tensor(boxs,dtype=torch.int)
a=torch.tensor(img,dtype=torch.uint8)
a=torchvision.utils.draw_bounding_boxes(image=a,boxes=boxs.unsqueeze(0),width=2,colors=(0,0,255))
a=a.permute(1,2,0)
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I need to draw a bounding box to the player's helmet. But bounding was drawn in a different location. I get bounding attributes from CSV files. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a top-left coordinate system while PyTorch uses `x`: horizontal left->right and `y`: vertical bottom->top. The bonding box provided to [`torchvision.utils.draw_bounding_boxes`](https://pytorch.org/vision/master/utils.html#torchvision.utils.draw_bounding_boxes) is defined as `(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)`.

Your mapping should therefore be:

```
xmin = left
ymin = top + height
xmax = left + width
ymax = top
```

Comment: Ok sure. i have a another doubt. i need to draw multiple bounding boxes. So can I use tensor or for loop?

Comment: Yes, you can use a for loop and apply `torchvision.utils.draw_bounding_boxes` multiple times

Comment: @18BCM061JoshuaJennySibbu Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, Thank You.

Comment: @18BCM061JoshuaJennySibbu Consider accepting the answer as valid, by clicking on the green checkmark on the left.